# Is it possible to drag and drop PNG images from your desktop into a running Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, xcode4.3, nsimageview

I want to build a Cocoa application where I'm able to just grab PNGs from either a folder or desktop, and drag and drop it into an already running Cocoa application window, and that application will take that png in and simply display it on the canvas. is that possible? If so, any leads to where I can begin looking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thinks there are 2 starting points in ADC docs, I personally used https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000384.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone cares, in order to do drag and drop, you work with NSDraggingDestination.